# 2 actions in 1 modal window for different controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

When creating a basket, a problem arose about how to remove an item from the list before checkout if the user changed his mind about buying it
The generated basket is sent to the address

```
//BasketViewModel
public class BasketViewModel
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public BasketDetailViewModel[] Details { get; set; }
}

public class BasketDetailViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public byte Count { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I send the collected order to the controller

```
//OrderController
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(BasketViewModel viewModel)
{
 some logic
}
```

and it works correctly - an order is created.

owever, if a client changes his mind about buying a product and he wants to remove it from the basket before registration, how can this be implemented. I understand that I can not use form inside form, however, when using jquery, the question arises because the basket is a modal window and is attached to the central template (_Layout) in the role of ViewComponent

_Layout.cshtml

```
 <head />
 ....
 <div class="body">
     @RenderBody()
 </div>
 <div class="modalViewBasket>
     @await Component.InvokeAsync("BasketDetail");
 </div>
 ....
 <footer/>
```

in this modal window, I have a button to delete goods from the basket

```
<div class="mr-4"> 
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnDelete" data-value="@Model.Details[i].ProductId">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I make sure that when I click on it, Id is sent from this modal window to the controller?

there may be some kind of ajax option, however, the scripts need to be implemented on the Layout, but how then to transfer which button was pressed if there are a lot of products in the basket?
because it uses a for loop to display all products

```
//BasketController
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    ...some logic
}
```

Modal basket

```
@model BasketViewModel

@{
Layout = null;
}

@if (Model.Details.Sum(x => x.Count) > 0)
{
<div class="modal fade cart-modal" id="cartModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Корзина (@Model.Details.Sum(x => x.Count))</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-controller="Order" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="col-12">
                    <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ClientName" class="control-label">Покупатель</label>
                                <input asp-for="ClientName" class="form-control" placeholder="Укажите имя" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="ClientName" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Phone" class="control-label">Телефон</label>
                                <input asp-for="Phone" id="phone-number" value="+7" class="form-control" placeholder="Укажите Телефон" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Details.Length; i++)
                    {

                        <div>
                            <div class="row align-items-center">
                                <div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-center">

                                    <div class="mr-4">
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnDelete" data-value="@Model.Details[i].ProductId">
                                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                            //here need send to /Basket/Delete/id
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Image -->
                                    <a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Get" asp-route-id="@Model.Details[i].ProductId">
                                        @{
                                            var image = $"~/images/{Model.Details[i].Image ?? "No_pic.png"}";
                                            <img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="..." width="auto" height="100">
                                        }

                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-7">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Details[i].ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display: none" } })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Details[i].Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display: none" } })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Details[i].Count, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display: none" } })
                                    <!-- Title -->
                                    <h6><a class="link-title" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Get" asp-route-id="@Model.Details[i].ProductId" asp-for="@Model.Details[i].ProductId">@Model.Details[i].Name</a></h6>
                                    <div class="product-meta">
                                        <span class="mr-2 text-primary">@Model.Details[i].Price.ToString("n2")</span><span class="text-muted">x @Model.Details[i].Count</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    }
                    <hr class="my-5">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-8">
                        <span class="text-muted">Итого к оплате:</span>  <span class="text-dark">@Model.Details.Sum(x => x.Count * x.Price).ToString("n2")</span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-animated mr-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-1"></i>Заказать
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` to function to get the button you pressed.Here is a demo showed how to pass id by ajax to controller:

_layout:

```
<div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
        <div>
         
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("BasketDetail",new BasketViewModel { ClientName= "ClientName",Phone="1111",Details=new  BasketDetailViewModel[] { new BasketDetailViewModel { ProductId=1, Name="p1",Count=1}, new BasketDetailViewModel { ProductId = 12, Name = "p2", Count = 1 }, new BasketDetailViewModel { ProductId = 3, Name = "p3", Count = 2 } } })
        </div>
        <button id="runButton" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Run</button>
    </div>
```

click method in _layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#runButton').click(function () {
            $("#cartModal").modal('show');
           
        });
        function deleteProduct(s) {
        var id = $(s).attr("data-value");
        $.ajax({

            url: "Tests/Delete/"+id,
            type: 'post',
            
            success: function (newItem) {
                //$(newItem).appendTo($('#items'))
            }
        })
    }
    </script>
```

The button to delete goods from the basket:

```
<div class="mr-4">
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnDelete" data-value="@Model.Details[i].ProductId" onclick="deleteProduct(this)">
                         <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                         //here need send to /Basket/Delete/id
               </a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var id1 = id; 
        }
```

result:
[image]